# Return two data frames from a function called in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Below is my function:

```
correct_occupancy <- function(testdf){

  occupied_dates_df <- data.frame(OccupiedDate = as.POSIXct(character()),
                                  Source = integer(),
                                  created = as.POSIXct(character()),
                                  Overwritten_cnt = integer(),
                                  testdf_row = integer()
                                 )


  ovrd_cnt= 0
  cond_ind = 0

  for (i in 1:nrow(testdf)){
    testspan <- seq(as.Date(testdf$check_in[i]), as.Date(testdf$check_out[i])-1, by="days")
    testspan <- as.data.frame(testspan)

    for(j in 1:nrow(testspan)){

      if(testspan$testspan[j] %in% occupied_dates_df[,1] == TRUE){

        lc <- which(occupied_dates_df[,1] == testspan$testspan[j], arr.ind=TRUE)
        if(occupied_dates_df$Source[lc] == testdf$connection_source[i]){
          testspan[j,1] <- NA
        }else{
          if(occupied_dates_df$Created[lc] < testdf$created[i]){
            testspan[j,1] <- NA
          }else{
            if(cond_ind == 0){
              cond_ind <- 1
            new_check_out <- data.frame(testspan = testdf$check_out[occupied_dates_df$testdf_row[lc]]-1)
            #print(new_check_out)
            testspan <- rbind(testspan,new_check_out)
            }                
            testdf$check_out[occupied_dates_df$testdf_row[lc]] <- testspan$testspan[1]
            occupied_dates_df$OccupiedDate[lc] <- testspan$testspan[j]
            occupied_dates_df$Source[lc] <- testdf$connection_source[i]
            occupied_dates_df$Created[lc] <- testdf$created[i]
            occupied_dates_df$Overwritten_cnt <- ovrd_cnt + 1
          }

        }

      }else{

        temp_dates_df = data.frame(OccupiedDate = testspan$testspan[j],
                                   Source = testdf$connection_source[i],
                                   Created = testdf$created[i],
                                   Overwritten_cnt = ovrd_cnt,
                                   testdf_row = i
        )
        occupied_dates_df <- rbind(occupied_dates_df,temp_dates_df)

      }

    }
    cond_ind <- 0
    testspan <- na.omit(testspan)
    if(nrow(testspan) != 0){
      testdf$check_in[i] <- min(testspan$testspan)
      testdf$check_out[i] <- max(testspan$testspan)+1

    }else{
      testdf$check_in[i] <- NA
      testdf$check_out[i] <- NA
    }
  }
  mylist = list(testdf=as.data.frame(testdf),occupied_dates_df=as.data.frame(occupied_dates_df))
  return(mylist)
}
```

And I am calling above function as below:

```
df_list1 <- testdf %>% split(list(.$FSID,.$PID),drop = TRUE) %>% map(~correct_occupancy(.))
```

Input Data:

```
structure(list(FSID = c(10729L, 10729L, 10729L, 10729L, 10729L, 
10729L, 10729L, 10729L, 10729L, 10729L), RID = 246:255, PID = c(52L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L), connection_source = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), check_in = structure(c(1496477160, 
1518264360, 1500390360, 1500426360, 1500538020, 1521814020, 1500624360, 
1500710760, 1500797160, 1524139560), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), check_out = structure(c(1500091200, 1519362000, 
1500523200, 1500436800, 1500609600, 1522555200, 1500696000, 1500782400, 
1501473600, 1524369600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    cancelled = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), created = structure(c(1500019607, 
    1500289617, 1500304017, 1500426413, 1500538021, 1500559624, 
    1500624418, 1500710819, 1500797219, 1501243611), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("FSID", "RID", "PID", 
"connection_source", "check_in", "check_out", "cancelled", "created"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("FSID", "PID"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:9), group_sizes = 10L, biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
    FSID = 10729L, PID = 52L), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("FSID", 
"PID"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("FSID", "PID")))
```

Below are my questions:

1)If I return only one dataframe from function,the code is working however the function gets executed number of times the groups are present in the input data sets. i.e if input data contains 28 rows with 5 groups result is 140 rows (result should be 28 rows only).

2) How do I return list (i.e. I want to return 2 dataframes from the function) from function called in dplyr.

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: If you want to operate by group but return a list of data frames, look into `purrr` instead. You can use `split` and `purrr:map` to operate in a similar way as `group_by` and `do(...)`

Comment: Thank you @CPak for the suggestion. I have used below code df_list1 <- testdf %>% split(list(.$Mer_ID,.$PID),drop = TRUE) %>% map(~correct_occupancy(.)). However while execution of map it gives error " Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument". Can you please suggest what must be reason of this error.

Comment: When I test the same code with smaller test dataset its working.

Comment: Could you edit your post with the code you tried and a small data set that reproduces the error?

Comment: @CPak actually when I am testing the code on small dataset its working. When I test it on actual dataset its giving error. And I have no clude for which record or list its giving error. Is there any way I can give you entire code and dataset?

Comment: I will add the code in post. However can you suggest how can I subset dataset where it produces error? Dataset is very big.

Comment: You can try splitting your data using `split(data, 1:10)` and then testing your function on each element

Comment: @CPak can you please check the code. My input dataframe i.e. testdf contains 167314 rows.

Comment: No, I'm sorry I cannot - could you follow the guidelines of SO - post a small reproducible example that reproduces your error - post minimal code that reproduces your error

Comment: @CPak I have updated the input data causing error. Can you please take a look.